how to fix clang: error: -lm: 'linker' input unused [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]?
I downloaded homebrew, gcc14 and pasted the path on compiler.
Then it worked when I pasted the flags:
 -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -lm -g"


But it didn’t build and showed:
FAILED: CMakeFiles/HW0.dir/main.c.o
/usr/bin/gcc   -Wall -Werror -lm -pedantic-errors -g -g -std=gnu99 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -fcolor-diagnostics -MD -MT CMakeFiles/HW0.dir/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/HW0.dir/main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/HW0.dir/main.c.o -c /Users/noharbatit/CLionProjects/HW0/main.c
clang: error: -lm: 'linker' input unused \[-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument\]
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


I have MacBook intel chip with macOS 15 sequoia
help please
I tried to redownload clion
homebrew
reinstall Xcode
paste path directly.
but it seems nothing is working

You mix a linker option with the compiler options. The linker option -l (lower-case L) is for linking a library. The compiler creating an object file have no need for it.

And don't set flags and options through variables like CMAKE_C_FLAGS. Use the suitable CMake commands instead: target_compile_options for compilation of source to object files; And target_link_libraries to link with libraries.

@Someprogrammerdude I pasted the exact flags the course gave me. it’s the demand of the course, I can’t do something else so it will pass tests

The problem might be that the tutor or teacher expects you to do it all manually on the command line, compiling and linking as a single step. If you use a tool like CMake (which CLion uses for its projects) then it will build as two different steps: Source to object file, and object file to executable program. You can still use the same flags the tutor/teacher told you to use, but you need to separate them them, so the compile-to-object file options are used only for that, and the link-to-executable flags are used only for that.

The changes you need to make in your CMakeLists.txt file is basically adding these two lines: target_compile_options(your_target PUBLIC  -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -g) and target_link_options(your_target PUBLIC m). All the options provided by your tutor/teacher are there, but placed in their correct places. The your_target symbol is the name in the add_executable command.
